# Creating and Using a C# DLL

Tags: c#, dll

I'm using VS 2010. I created a C# Class and compiled it to a DLL, then added a windows forms project to it to test the dll. I added a Reference to the DLL in the TestApp project in the Solution Explorer. Both projects compile without errors. But when I run the TestApp, I get a NullReferenceException when I call a method in the dll. The error says there is no instance of the object, which I unsterstand to be the method being called.

Everything I've done is the same as other DLL examples I've found on the internet. For example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z(v=vs.100).aspx

http://coderock.net/how-to-create-a-dll-file-in-visual-studio-2010/

But I've obviously missed something basic.

// DLL Project

```
namespace SLink
{
    public class AmpAPI
    {
        public String[] ReadID( Int32 id )
        {
            String[] result = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

// Test Application

```
using SLink;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        AmpAPI amp;

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmMain_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            amp = new AmpAPI();
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            String[] result = new String[] { "", "", "", "" };
            result = amp.ReadID( 0 ); // <-- NullReferenceException
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the stack trace? What do you see in the debugger?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your `frmMain_Load` method is not being called when the form loads.

Did you just copy and paste the code? That's not enough to register the method as an event handler for the `Load` event.

- You can add a new handler to the form's `Load` event by double clicking the form in the designer. Then you can edit the body of the method.
- Alternatively you can choose an existing method to handle the event. To do this click the form in the designer, go to properties, select events, find `Load`, then select your method from the drop-down list.

[image: Add handler to Load event in WinForms designer]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private void btnUpdate_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        String[] result = amp.ReadID( 0 );
    }
```

Not sure if it is liking your previous implementation for initializing the array.